# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.sqlalchemy'

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy on airflow AWS.
for some resons I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.sqlalchemy',
even thought I have it in my requirments.txt.

anyone know how to fix it? I'm trying to use it with PythonOperator. I also tried to specify the package:
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check Airflow worker group logs. If there is any issue with the module, it will be shown in logs.